# Pointers in cpp

Tags: c++, c++11

I have next example in book

```
const int** pp2;
int* p1;
const int n = 13;
pp2 = &p1; // not allowed, but suppose it were
*pp2 = &n; // valid, both const, but sets p1 to point at n
*p1 = 10; // valid, but changes const n
```

But how expression *pp2=&n can be valid, if pp2 is pointer-to-const?

Answer (score 5):

> if pp2 is pointer-to-const?

`pp2` is **not** a pointer to const. It is a non-const **pointer to non-const** pointer to const int.

As such, there is no problem with modifying `*pp2` which is a non-const pointer to const int. What would not be allowed is to modify `**pp2` which is const int.

Answer (score 2):

`pp2` is not "pointer-to-const". pp2 is a pointer to a pointer to a `const`.

Therefore, `*pp2` is a pointer to a `const`. This pointer is not `const` itself, it's perfectly valid to modify it to some other pointer to a `const`.